# Problems with custom taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Let's cut right to the chase:
I have two custom post types: **interviews** and **people**. They both have custom taxonomy **names**. In interviews there is a video interview with one particular person along with the transcript of the video. In people, there is a short biography and a photo of that person.

On my home page I want to display randomly picked interview: title, short excerpt of the video interview transcript - and I need a photo of that person. Which I need to pull from the custom post type for that person which is **people** custom post type.

The way I figure it out is that I need a query within a query. First is to pick a random interview and then to somehow find the **people** post with the same **names** term as that particular random interview.

Can someone help me with this?

@toscho ok, so this is my code with post 2 post plugin:

```
<?php query_posts(
        array (
            'post_type' => 'interviews',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            )
        );
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

    <?php
    // Find connected pages
    $connected = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'people',
        'connected_from' => get_queried_object_id(),
        )
    );
    // Display connected pages
    while ( $connected->have_posts() ) : $connected->the_post();?>
        <h2>Person in this interview: <?php the_title();?></h2>
    <?php endwhile;
    // Prevent weirdness
    wp_reset_postdata();?>

    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();?>
```

It still doesn't work. It displays all the peoples' names, no matter which one is connected to that interview

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Plugin Post2Post](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/) to associate the interviews with the people and to get these associations to your query.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It was the weird french characters, like **é**